# Phrase that means "gaining money for someone" in a negative context

Tags: phrases, expressions, translation

In German, we have a phrase *"jmd. in die Tasche spielen"*, literally *"to play into someone's pockets"*. I am looking for a fitting English equivalent.

The phrase means, you are causing a third party financial gain with your actions.
These words are nearly always used in a negative context.

For more details read on:
In a story, a character is asked to do a small favor, but by doing so an unnamed third party would gain money. Sarcastically, he responds: *"Sure, I'll play into their pockets"*.

I'm looking for an actual phrase that keeps the meaning but is valid English.

Comment: I'm sure there must be better words, but *"Sure, I will run small errands for them."* comes to mind. Another one is *"Sure, I will get my commission later."*

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, but: *be a cat's paw, be someone's tool / lackey, be a doormat, dance 
to someone else's tune, do someone's dirty work*

Comment: I like the question, but I do not have a good answer.  "I've got my hand in his pocket"  suggest that I am stealing from him, but I cannot think of an English equivalent when a third party is benefiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several idiomatic phrases in English that have to do with activities that result in another's financial gain, such as

> *[line someones pockets](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/line+pockets)*
>
> and
>
> *[feather one's own nest](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/feather+nest)*

but those are more often used to describe a self serving activity, one's own gain.

The phrase  is often used to describe working at the direction of, and for the benefit of, another but does not have specific financial implications, and reflects a direct, rather than a collateral benefit.

The closest I can think of is **[play into his hands](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+into+hands)**

> to assist one in one's scheming without realizing it

This generally reflects a battle of wills and may or may not concern financial matters.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm going to go with "line their pockets".

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "working for the man" has some of this flavor to it, and there are various quotes from the song "Sixteen Tons" that show up sometimes:

```
You load Sixteen Tons, and what do you get?
Another day older, and deeper in debt.
St. Peter don't you call me, cause I can't go,
I owe my soul to the company store.
```

The most common phrase in English in this space has things turned around, however; the third party is earning money "on the backs of" the other people.

Answer (score 1):

**line somebody's pockets**  - I think this is a right fit here.

If money or a system is lining someone's pockets, that person is receiving too much money or is receiving money that is not intended for them There's to be an investigation following allegations that the money raised is lining the pockets of officials.

got this from - http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pocket

Answer (score 1):

> [***to play into the hands of***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+into+the+hands+of)
>
> to give someone an advantage -  *If this information is made public, it will play into the hands of people who are demanding an investigation of the police.*
> Usage notes: usually an advantage one person believes another should not have